# Error on membership fee token when using Print/Merge Document

Tags: core

I did a short test on the demo sandbox.

Selected "Find Membership" and selected one record.
I then choose Print/Merge Document and added 2 tokens, {membership.id} and {membership.fee}
Then clicked "Preview" to see the pdf outcome.

If I use only the token {membership.id} I do not get any error message and the preview is created.

Adding {membership.fee} I get the following error message below.

Is this effectively a bug or am I doing something wrong? Thanks for your feedback.

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
TypeError: Return value of CRM_Utils_Money::formatUSLocaleNumericRounded() must be of the type string, null returned in CRM_Utils_Money::formatUSLocaleNumericRounded() (line 207 of /srv/buildkit/build/d9-master/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/Money.php).

CRM_Utils_Money::formatUSLocaleNumericRounded() (Line: 249)
CRM_Utils_Money::formatLocaleNumericRoundedByPrecision() (Line: 234)
CRM_Utils_Money::formatLocaleNumericRoundedByCurrency() (Line: 281)
CRM_Utils_Money::formatLocaleNumericRoundedForDefaultCurrency() (Line: 65)
CRM_Member_Tokens->evaluateToken() (Line: 146)
Civi\Token\AbstractTokenSubscriber->evaluateTokens() (Line: 264)
Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() (Line: 239)
Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->callListeners() (Line: 73)
Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() (Line: 209)
Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch() (Line: 354)
Civi\Token\TokenProcessor->evaluate() (Line: 64)
CRM_Core_TokenSmarty::render() (Line: 349)
CRM_Core_BAO_MessageTemplate::renderTemplateRaw() (Line: 271)
CRM_Core_BAO_MessageTemplate::renderTemplate() (Line: 131)
CRM_Member_Form_Task_PDFLetter->generateHTML() (Line: 98)
CRM_Member_Form_Task_PDFLetter->postProcessMembers() (Line: 75)
CRM_Member_Form_Task_PDFLetter->postProcess() (Line: 573)
CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess() (Line: 56)
CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Submit->perform() (Line: 203)
HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle() (Line: 103)
HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle() (Line: 355)
CRM_Core_Controller->run() (Line: 319)
CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem() (Line: 69)
CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke() (Line: 36)
CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke() (Line: 88)
Drupal\civicrm\Civicrm->invoke() (Line: 80)
Drupal\civicrm\Controller\CivicrmController->main()
call_user_func_array() (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 564)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext() (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext() (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 158)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() (Line: 80)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle() (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass() (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle() (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle() (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle() (Line: 709)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug and I can reproduce it on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org. Can you file a bug report at https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues?

It looks like the problem is here, where it can't find the type: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/639e58b05319f32a29b09eace7d00e9609cb86e4/CRM/Member/Tokens.php#L64

Comment: There is a bug report now at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3805. A fix is available, but not yet upstream.